# Parse '.caffemodel.h5' for Lasagne

Tags: theano, caffe, lasagne

I have trained a model from caffe in ".caffemodel.h5" format. I want to parse it to extract parameters and feed it to a lasagne model. How can I do it?

Comment: What is your motivation to do this? Maybe there are other ways of achieving your goal.

Comment: I want to try lasagne for training CNN for cifar10 dataset, but it is taking too much time to train. I have pretrained caffe model, I want to load it to Lasagne and try some operations on it.

Comment: OK. Why don't you do these operations in pycaffe? What is the nature of these operations?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replicate the architecture of your caffemodel in terms of Lasagne layers first, by hand, or use a script that does this (a script that takes a caffe protobuf and translates it to lasagne exists AFAIK, or should be made if not. In any case it exists in sklearn-theano.)

By hand, you need to open the hf5 file using e.g. `pytables`, and then replicate the architecture in Lasagne.